# Loading images in a Listview properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I'm using the Universal Image Loader library to load images in my listview, it loads the images but I notice that if you scroll quickly the first time you can see the wrong images being loaded first before the correct image.

How can I stop this effect. Here is my entire class below.

```
public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<VenueDetails> m_venue_details) {
    super(context, R.layout.venue_list_row, m_venue_details);

    this.context = context;
    this.venue_details = new ArrayList<VenueDetails>();
    this.venue_details = m_venue_details;
    df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    final VenueDetails vD =  venue_details.get(position);   

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_list_row, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.venue_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_name);
        holder.venue_dist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_dist);
        holder.curr_loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.curr_loc);
        holder.ll = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_frame);
        holder.pett_btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_pett);
        holder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_logo);

        v.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.img.setTag(vD.logo);

    if(vD.list_img == null){
        myAppObj.getImageLoader().loadImage(holder.img.getTag().toString(), new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.placeholder_venue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                    FailReason failReason) {    
                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.placeholder_pin);                   
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                holder.img.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));
                if(vD.list_img == null){
                    vD.list_img = new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.placeholder_venue);
            }
        });
    }else{
        holder.img.setBackgroundDrawable(vD.list_img);
    }

    if(vD != null){         

        holder.venue_name.setText(vD.venueName.toUpperCase());
        venue_details.get(position).venue_distance = Double.parseDouble(df.format(Utils.distance(myAppObj.getMyLatitude(), myAppObj.getMyLongitude(), vD.latitude, vD.longitude, 'K') * 0.000621371192));
        holder.venue_dist.setText(df.format(vD.venue_distance)+" Miles");


        holder.venue_curr_loc.setText(my_address.toUpperCase());

        if (vD.petted == 1) {

            holder.pett_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.pett_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {                   
                    if(dialog_Callback!=null)
                        dialog_Callback.onDialogCalled(0, vD.id);
                }
            });

        } else {

            holder.pett_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }           
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (venue_details.get(position).petted == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView venue_name;
    TextView venue_dist;
    TextView venue_curr_loc;
    FrameLayout ll;
    Button pett_btn;
    ImageView img;
}
```

Comment: On your DisplayImageOptions put this .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) very easy to use and much better performace

Answer (score 2):

Its because its recycling views, so that second argument (View v) in getView already holds the content from a previous list item. So you need to clear that imageView as it won't change immediately (due to the image being downloaded).

Changing your code to something like this should work

```
if (v == null) { 

...

}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    holder.img.setImageResource(0);
    holder.img.setBackgroundDrawable(0);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make alot of change to it

Comment: For me also doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem before and i realized that:
First:
1- The class that the AsyncTask that present in your Universal Image Loader library should have a WeakReference for the imageView that the image will be load in.

2- while scrolling and displaying a row with an image its AsyncTask is still getting the image, you have to be sure that there is no other AsyncTask will be start for the same image.

after a long searching journey to fix your exact problem i found another class you can customize it to fit your requirements.

```
package com.nweave.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.nweave.view.ProductArrayAdapter;

public class ImageDownloader {
    private ProductArrayAdapter productArrayAdapter;

    public ImageDownloader(ProductArrayAdapter productArrayAdapter) {
        this.productArrayAdapter = productArrayAdapter;
    }

    public void download(String name, String url, ImageView imageView,
            ProgressBar progressBar) {
        if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = new BitmapDownloaderTask(
                    name, imageView, progressBar);
            DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(
                    bitmapDownloaderTask);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
            bitmapDownloaderTask.execute(url);
        }
    }

    private class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        String url;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private final String productName;
        private final ProgressBar progressbar;

        public BitmapDownloaderTask(String name, ImageView imageView,
                ProgressBar progressBar) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            productName = name;
            progressbar = progressBar;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpClient httpsClient = getHttpsClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
            try {
                httpGet.setURI(new URI(params[0]));

                response = httpsClient.execute(httpGet);
                Bitmap currentBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());
                productArrayAdapter.cacheImages.saveImages(productName,
                        currentBitMap);
                return currentBitMap;
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e(ImageDownloader.class.getSimpleName() + ":doInBackground",
                        e.getMessage());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(ImageDownloader.class.getSimpleName() + ":doInBackground",
                        e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(ImageDownloader.class.getSimpleName() + ":doInBackground",
                        e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                result = null;
            }
            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = ImageDownloader
                        .getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

        public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
            bitmapDownloaderTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(
                    bitmapDownloaderTask);
        }

        public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
            return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url,
            ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
        if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
            String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
            if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(
            ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable) drawable;
                return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static HttpClient getHttpsClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(
                    trustStore);
            sslSocketFactory
                    .setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(ImageDownloader.class.getSimpleName() + ":getHttpsClient",
                    e.getMessage());
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```